# Some advice how print in WPF with good result

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

next month I will begin to develop a project and I'm studying about that (I'm a novice).

In this project I will create many report storing data from a Database so I'm concentrating about how print the report using WPF. I need to use many features as follows: page header, page Footer, multi page, page number and so on.

I ask you if you can give me any useful advice, links, suggestion, tools etc. to help me how print in WPF with good results, sincerely I have not good knowledge about that.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Kind of surprised you didn't see this question in the suggestions as you typed your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf

Comment: @Matt: that question is only remotely similar to this one, and also has only very unsatisfying answers IMHO.

Comment: It's only remotely similar? Am I misreading? He's asking about reporting/printing from WPF, isn't he?

Comment: HI ,
Mr.Matt i did not read your question however it's an answer.My difficult stay to find out a good method to print my reports,i have a method to create report without use tools so i need to study a good method to print my report .
Hoping to try a good solution and thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are concerned with two things: printing, and reporting.

If it is a simple matter of printing, then [there are other questions out there](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=print+WPF) that may help.

If you are concerned primarily with reporting, or managing and printing reports, then you want a reporting framework.

If you have licensed SQL Server 2005 or later, you may want to check out [SQL Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106(SQL.90).aspx).  You can use SSRS regardless of whether the data is stored in SQL Server.

The suggestion in the comments to your question - to view [this prior SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf) -  still seems like a good one to me.  It is nearly an identical question.

Comment: @cHESSO.hi ,i'm trying to understand how Print my report in multipage ,because i have many report so long to enter in one page and so i don't know exactly how work out this feature .To build the report is not a trouble for me (luckily) .
Thanks for your answer

Comment: if you are using WPF, the FlowDocument can be repaginated for printer output devices, pretty easily.  Check those links I suggested.