# Reporting options for a WPF application?

Tags: wpf, reporting

I'd like to integrate some high-level reports into my WPF application. Essentially, the user will enter some parameters, press a "Go" button, and will be presented with their report.

A report will consist of some text, some tables and some charts.

What technologies, tools and libraries are available to my WPF application?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf) seems to be a similar one.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a colleague use Active Reports (and any report builder would do it), generate the report, export to image (1 page = 1 image), and load the individual images in a FlowDocument. Then you'd have built-in functionality to go back and forth, zooming, and all the goodness the FlowDocument provides.
I know this work-aroundish but this solution has 2 benefits: 1) you're not tied to any particular report builder and 2) you don't need to use the WindowsFormsHost, which you can't use in partial-trust scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Two options that are out of the box in visual studio (Pro or higher):
Crystal Reports
OR
SQL Server Reports (SSRS)

In WPF you can host the crystal report viewer or the SSRS viewer inside the windows forms host control.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at Active Reports.You can go through this blog for more information

http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2011/11/how-to-view-report-created-using-active.html

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to [infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf/reporting.aspx). They have a complete wpf reporting solution into their WPF NetAdvantage library.

Comment: Infragistics Reporting is not used for display of report data. It is used to write WPF content to XPS for printing etc.

Answer (score -1):

The best option I know is **MS Word**:

1. You have to implement all filters you need for the particular report within your app.
2. You have to integrate **MS Word** in your  application and it means you have to present in the report some data that user can use.
3. You have to provide to user detail user's manual how to use replaceable variables in MS Word so they can use it properly.
4. Provide possibility that user can upload MS Word report templates to the server side.

In that case user can build use all data o part of the data you  are providing for the certain report and in places he wants as well as use can use any design of report is based on **MS Word** functionality.