# Design for Report engine

Tags: report

Hai,
i am in a project related to designing the architecture for a report engine..which will generate variety of reports which are editable by the user.There will be a preview section similar to MSPublisher preview as well in the report engine.So i want to refer some projects related to this kind to get some idea about this preview and generating reports ..we are doing it in WPF. So what are the useful resources that i can find it to go through and get some knowledge
Thanx in advance
Kaja

Comment: If you need source code, ask for an open-source solution, and specify your target programming language.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf

Answer (score 2):

If you have a copy of Microsoft Access (version 97 or greater), their report engine is a pretty good model to follow.

There is also Crystal Reports.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said you were DESIGNING the report engine.  I didn't realize this was a plzsndtehcodez question.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna exactly familiar open-source projects, then look there:

- BIRT;
- JasperReport;
- ReportServer.

Also you can try to use [FastReport.Net](https://www.fast-report.com/en/product/fast-report-net) and get some useful information about report generators. And it has source codes too.