# DocumentPaginator that works with any Visual?

Tags: wpf, printing, uielement, documentpaginator

Printing any visual is easy.

Printing one that is larger than a single page is hard.

I'm stuck.  The docs are scarce and I've gotten as far as I can.

I'm wondering if anybody has a class which extends DocumentPaginator that can take any visual (or even a UIElement) and split it across multiple pages.  I attempted to create one, but I can't manage to do anything except print the first page over and over.

Please, I've seen all the links out there.  Pasting links that do not specifically satisfy the question are pointless.  Practical experience would be a +.

Comment: Will did you find an answer for this question?

Comment: @WiiMaxx: Nope.  And, honestly, this question is off topic.  Should have closed it a while ago, as I'm just asking for a library/links, essentially.  The sad truth is that you have to handle pagination yourself, creating an implementation that fits your requirements.  There isn't any one-size-fits-all solution.

Comment: Too bad. I was hopping i could save some time :(