# WPF Reporting Solution

Tags: wpf, reporting

I have a WPF application with a Sql Server backend and need to produce a series of reports within it.  I am currently using Stored procs to retrieve the data for the reports as some of the data is quite complex, and then displaying them through the Telerik Report Viewer.  This works fine however I would like to be able to create reports that feel a bit more up to date, e.g. contain some animations, use 3D charts, that kind of thing.

What are some recommended reporting solutions that fit these criteria? :

- Use Stored Procedures for the data (and to populate any lookup parameters)
- Be very visually appealing, support 3D charts, gradient fills, dashboard style controls
- Be either free (or cheap, ideally < $1000)
- Ideally integrate within VS although this is not essential

Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best approach to printing/reporting from WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf)

Comment: @Matt, I did look at this question however it was asked in 2008 when there didn't seem to be many controls specifically for WPF around.  The question also focusses on the ability to print which although I would expect this to be part of any reporting control, my requirements are a bit more specific

Comment: No worries Macros. Your justification should be enough to stop anyone else from voting to close.

Comment: Have a look at this Tools: http://gamadev.com/?p=11175

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid SQL Reporting Services with the [Dundas controls](http://www.dundas.com/), then you can build your own report presentations using WPF - it has all the graphic snazziness™ you could need, including transforms, storyboards, vector drawing, etc.

Comment: I had thought about this however time is a real factor and I just don't have enough of it to roll my own

Comment: @Macros - did you notice the link to Dundas? They do some very nice controls.