# Python or WPF reporting application

Tags: python, wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have an existing VS-2008 Windows application with back-end MySQL Server 5.5. The existing application uses Crystal Reports for reporting. I want to get rid of Crystal Reports and want to use another tool that seamlessly integrates with VS-2010 Express. I want to remove reporting options from my existing application and want to write a new WPF reporting application using VS-2010 Express. I want a free tool but as I am using MySQL, tools like SSRS are not useful for me.

What are the options? I am planning the other way round by writing a Python reporting application powered by any open-source Python reporting tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WPF you can use http://wpfreports.codeplex.com/ for simple reports or follow this article instructions to make you own: http://janrep.blog.codeplant.net/post/WPF-Multipage-Reports-Part-I.aspx

I've used SSRS, but only the RDLC part (you can use it with any datasource), but not very happy with the results and WPF does not have a native RDLC ReportViewer.

Also check this related question [What's the best approach to printing/reporting from WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Why not have both? [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) is a python implementation on top of .NET. It allows you to write code that is totally python, but gives you access to all of .NET, including WPF.

For a quick look at what this looks like, [here](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/XAML_GUI_Events_Example) is a basic WPF project using ironpython.

Comment: But which reporting tool to use? I don't want to use Crystal Reports from IronPython.