# Create User control with databinding only for printing it

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to print a user control with data binding.
I'm very confused about this and don't even know if it is possible.
I have a class which implements **DocumentPaginator**
and I would like to do something like this:

```
public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
{
    UserControl myUC = new View.MyUserControl();
    myUC.DataContext = this;
    return new DocumentPage(myUC);
}
```

The xaml of myUC user control contains a label like the following:

```
   <Label Content="{Binding myName}" FontSize="18"  Height="20"/>
```

where myName is a property defined in the class.

The user control is correctly printed but the binding is not applied. 
Is it possible some way ? What can I do ?

Please considered this is an extremely simplified example of what I would like to do. My final goal is more like design a form in xaml and then print it with my data.

Update

I will read [this post more carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180746/whats-the-best-approach-to-printing-reporting-from-wpf).
At a first try calling **Measure, Arrange, and UpdateLayout** on the user control seem promising for my goal.

Comment: Have you verified that your data binding works before attempting to print?

Comment: Verified ! Something goes better after calling **updateLayout()** but I still have troubles if I have a ListView with a data- binding on itemsource.